# Vector being cast from a central point

Tags: math, geometry

I want to break a circle up into X number of rays that will fire out from a given point.

The problem I'm having is how do I calculate the vector of each ray given X which is the number of rays fired equal distance from each other around a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2π radians (360 degrees) in a circle. You want to divide this value by X to tell you the difference of angle that you need between each ray. Call this difference Z. Start with a ray pointing at 0 radians, and repeatedly add Z to it. At each iteration, generate a new ray, and stop after X iterations.

For each ray above defined by its value in radians, use trigonometry (sine and cosine) to construct the X and Y component values of the ray direction vector.